# Spark program taking hadoop configurations from an unspecified location

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I have few test cases such as reading/writing a file on HDFS that I want to automate using Scala and run using maven. I have taken the Hadoop configuration files of test environment and put it in the resources directory of my maven project. The project is also running fine on the desired cluster from any cluster that I am using to run the project from.

One thing that I am not getting is how is Spark taking Hadoop configurations from resources directory even when I have not specified it anywhere in the project. Below is a code snippet from project.

```
def getSparkContext(hadoopConfiguration: Configuration): SparkContext ={
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkTest").setMaster("local")     
    val hdfsCoreSitePath = new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml","core-site.xml")
    val hdfsHDFSSitePath = new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml","hdfs-site.xml")
    val hdfsYarnSitePath = new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml","yarn-site.xml")
    val hdfsMapredSitePath = new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml","mapred-site.xml")
    hadoopConfiguration.addResource(hdfsCoreSitePath)
    hadoopConfiguration.addResource(hdfsHDFSSitePath)
    hadoopConfiguration.addResource(hdfsYarnSitePath)
    hadoopConfiguration.addResource(hdfsMapredSitePath)
    hadoopConfiguration.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos")
    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(hadoopConfiguration)
    UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("alice", "/etc/security/keytab/alice.keytab")
    println("-----------------Logged-in via keytab---------------------")
    FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration)
    val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
    return sc
  }
@Test
def testCase(): Unit = {
    var hadoopConfiguration: Configuration = new Configuration()
    val sc=getSparkContext(hadoopConfiguration)
    //rest of the code
    //...
    //...
  }
```

Here, I have used `hadoopconfiguration` object but I am not specifying this anywhere to `sparkContext` as this will run the tests on the cluster which I am using for running the project and not on some remote test environment.

If this is not a correct way? Can anyone please explain how I should carry out my motive of running spark test-cases on test environment from some remote cluster?

Comment: Resources are placed on the classpath, and configuration files on the classpath are used automatically.

Comment: maven may place the resources on the classpath but how does my program take some files "automatically" without being specified? Moreover, when i create a new directory inside resources directory and place those files inside that directory, then it takes the Hadoop config files from the cluster(/etc/hadoop/conf) that I am using to run the tests.

Comment: 1) Spark picks from the `$SPARK_HOME/conf` and `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` 2) The `Configuration` object has defaults in it. If you don't want them, use `new Configuration(false)`

Comment: Nit-picking about the comment by @cricket_007 > Spark adds `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and/or `$YARN_CONF_DIR` and/or `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` entries in the CLASSPATH, after Spark's own conf dir which is is set via `$SPARK_CONF_DIR` _(defaulted to `$SPARK_HOME/conf`)_ >> cf. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/launcher/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/AbstractCommandBuilder.java

Comment: But beware, when running Spark-on-YARN, the Spark launcher process will ship a copy of **all** config files found in `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and/or `$YARN_CONF_DIR` to the YARN containers -- but **not all** files found in `$SPARK_CONF_DIR`, just a few (e.g. Log4J conf). Specifically, if you drop a `hive-site.xml` in Spark conf dir then in _yarn-cluster_ mode the driver will not find it! >> cf. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/Client.scala

Comment: @Samson The hive site problem was fixed in the latest release, I believe